# iopart class is in the local tex, but I got the error : 'iopart class is not found'

Tags: class, latex

This is the first time I use `iopart.cls`, and I have faced different problems.  However, the required files are available in the [main file](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/), I got this error:
[image].
Many thanks in advance.

```
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./IOPLaTeXGuidelines.tex
(IOPLaTeXGuidelines.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2022-11-02> (iopart.cls
Document Class: iopart 1996/06/10 v0.0 IOP Journals LaTeX article class
(iopart10.clo
File: iopart10.clo 1997/01/13 v1.0 IOP Book file (size option)
)
\c@jnl=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\indentedwidth=\skip49
\mathindent=\dimen140
\c@eqnval=\count193
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.
cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.de
f
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen143
\lightrulewidth=\dimen144
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen145
\belowrulesep=\dimen146
\belowbottomsep=\dimen147
\aboverulesep=\dimen148
\abovetopsep=\dimen149
\cmidrulesep=\dimen150
\cmidrulekern=\dimen151
\defaultaddspace=\dimen152
\@cmidla=\count194
\@cmidlb=\count195
\@aboverulesep=\dimen153
\@belowrulesep=\dimen154
\@thisruleclass=\count196
\@lastruleclass=\count197
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen155
) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/units\nicefrac.sty
Package: nicefrac 1998/08/04 v0.9b Nice fractions
\L@UnitsRaiseDisplaystyle=\skip50
\L@UnitsRaiseTextstyle=\skip51
\L@UnitsRaiseScriptstyle=\skip52

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
))
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip53

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen156
))
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen157
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count199
\leftroot@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count267
\DOTSCASE@=\count268
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen158
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count269
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count270
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count271
\dspbrk@lvl=\count272
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count273
\column@=\count274
\maxfields@=\count275
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen159
\alignsep@=\dimen160
\tagshift@=\dimen161
\tagwidth@=\dimen162
\totwidth@=\dimen163
\lineht@=\dimen164
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip54
\multlinetaggap=\skip55
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathtools\mathtools.st
y
Package: mathtools 2022/06/29 v1.29 mathematical typesetting tools
 (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count276
\calc@Bcount=\count277
\calc@Adimen=\dimen165
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen166
\calc@Askip=\skip56
\calc@Bskip=\skip57
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count278
\calc@Cskip=\skip58
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathtools\mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
)
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count279
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen167
\origjot=\skip59
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen168
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen169
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen170
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen171
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen172
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen173
\xmathstrut@box=\box53
\xmathstrut@dim=\dimen174
) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/multirow\multirow.sty
Package: multirow 2021/03/15 v2.8 Span multiple rows of a table
\multirow@colwidth=\skip60
\multirow@cntb=\count280
\multirow@dima=\skip61
\bigstrutjot=\dimen175
) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/subfloat\subfloat.st
y
Package: subfloat 2003/08/21 version 2.14
Package `subfloat', Version 2.14 of 2003/08/21.

Package subfloat Warning: Numbers of floats not counted:
(subfloat)                If you use one of the counters subfloatfiguremax or
(subfloat)                subfloattablemax you will get strange error messages
(subfloat)                containing \c@subfloatfiguremax or
(subfloat)                \c@subfloattablemax:
(subfloat)                Please switch on countmax or remove the code using
(subfloat)                the counter then..

) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/subfig\subfig.sty
Package: subfig 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2022/03/01 v3.6b Customizing captions (AR)

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2022/03/17 v2.3b caption3 kernel (AR)
\caption@tempdima=\dimen176
\captionmargin=\dimen177
\caption@leftmargin=\dimen178
\caption@rightmargin=\dimen179
\caption@width=\dimen180
\caption@indent=\dimen181
\caption@parindent=\dimen182
\caption@hangindent=\dimen183
Package caption Info: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)             standard defaults will be used.
Package caption Info: \@makecaption = \long macro:#1#2->\vskip \abovecaptionski
p \begin {indented} \item []{\bf #1.} #2 \end {indented}\vskip \belowcaptionski
p  on input line 1176.
)

Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

\c@caption@flags=\count281
\c@continuedfloat=\count282
)
\c@KVtest=\count283
\sf@farskip=\skip62
\sf@captopadj=\dimen184
\sf@capskip=\skip63
\sf@nearskip=\skip64
\c@subfigure=\count284
\c@subfigure@save=\count285
\c@lofdepth=\count286
\c@subtable=\count287
\c@subtable@save=\count288
\c@lotdepth=\count289
\sf@top=\skip65
\sf@bottom=\skip66
) (C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/gensymb\gensymb.sty
Package: gensymb 2022/10/17 v1.0.2 (KJH)
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pd
ftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-10-26 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count290
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
) (IOPLaTeXGuidelines.aux)
\openout1 = `IOPLaTeXGuidelines.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 66.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.m
kii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count291
\scratchdimen=\dimen185
\scratchbox=\box55
\nofMPsegments=\count292
\nofMParguments=\count293
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count294
\MPscratchDim=\dimen186
\MPnumerator=\count295
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count296
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
)
(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-
base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.
cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: subfig package v1.3 is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \celsius on input line 66.
Package gensymb Info: Faking symbols for \degree and \celsius on input line 66.



Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \ohm on input line 66.
Package gensymb Info: Using \Omega for \ohm on input line 66.

Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.

[1

{C:/Users/Sara/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 102
.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 102
.

(C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
Underfull \hbox (badness 2253) in paragraph at lines 102--103
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 with Gaussian-modulated coherent state (GMCS)
 []

Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <fig1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2022-10-08 09:34:04
(epstopdf)                    size: 133304182 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2022-10-24 22:50:10
(epstopdf)                    size: 711753 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <miktex-epstopdf --outfile=fig1-eps-converted-t
o.pdf fig1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 108.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
<fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=12, 7842.29875pt x 1916.15875pt>
File: fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on input line 108.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 487.8225pt x 119.17487pt.

Underfull \hbox (badness 1009) in paragraph at lines 106--112
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 the huge difference between the optical power of
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1253) in paragraph at lines 112--113
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 performance of the scheme. The delay-line and
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1331) in paragraph at lines 112--113
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 assisted feed-forward, have been proposed in the
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1137) in paragraph at lines 112--113
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 extinction ratios of multiplexer and demultiplexer
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 2865) in paragraph at lines 112--113
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 devices. Then, many efforts have been made
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1348) in paragraph at lines 113--113
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 on Bob's side. It is attempted to demonstrate
 []

[2

] [3 <./fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf>]
Underfull \hbox (badness 2495) in paragraph at lines 117--117
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 in lasers. In this technique, phase, frequency
 []

[4]
Underfull \hbox (badness 1546) in paragraph at lines 186--186
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 and carriers in the semiconductor lasers lead to
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 3386) in paragraph at lines 186--186
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 fluctuations in the output intensity, phase and
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 2111) in paragraph at lines 186--186
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Langevin sources [[]] into rate equations, while
 []

[5]

LaTeX Font Warning: Command \footnotesize invalid in math mode on input line 21
2.


Underfull \hbox (badness 1742) in paragraph at lines 221--222
$\OML/cmm/m/it/9 ^^N[]$\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 , $\OML/cmm/m/it/9 ^^N[]$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/9 
and $\OML/cmm/m/it/9 ^^N[]$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/9 are the fluctuations of the photon
 []

Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <fig2.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2022-06-28 18:39:03
(epstopdf)                    size: 25529603 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <fig2-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2022-10-24 22:51:06
(epstopdf)                    size: 243581 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <miktex-epstopdf --outfile=fig2-eps-converted-t
o.pdf fig2.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 228.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
<fig2-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=36, 2126.94624pt x 1337.99875pt>
File: fig2-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use fig2-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig2-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on input line 228.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 219.51863pt x 138.07469pt.

Underfull \hbox (badness 1917) in paragraph at lines 225--232
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 where $\OMS/cmsy/m/n/9 h\OML/cmm/m/it/9 XY\OMS/cmsy/m/n/9 i[]$ \
OT1/cmr/m/n/9 represents the spectral density of the
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1163) in paragraph at lines 244--246
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 where $\OML/cmm/m/it/9 D\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 (\OML/cmm/m/it/9 !\OT1/cm
r/m/n/9 )$ is the determinant of matrix $\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 M$\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 . The

 []

[6 <./fig2-eps-converted-to.pdf>]
Overfull \hbox (124.63255pt too wide) in alignment at lines 274--296
[] [] [] [] [] []
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1205) in paragraph at lines 300--301
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 The most important challenge in the LLO CV-QKD
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1824) in paragraph at lines 300--301
\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 schemes is the excess noise derived from the phase
 []
```

and this is the main file:
[image]. I searched about the similar question and despite them the required files are in the main file

Comment: Can you show your .log file? And tell us where you put the .cls file? The image you show is just from your editor, not a real latex error.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you. Sorry about this delay. I added the log file. I add these files in the main file similar to this page : https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/

Comment: Your latex finds the class just fine. The "error" you see is just from your editor - nothing relevant.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for your help.  can I ask you a favor? I have another question related to this class here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666487/reference-section-with-spaced-words-and-unjustified-items. I dont know why this file is so messed-up. I really apprecite your help

Comment: You seem to have some problems with your editor configurations. You use an online LaTeX editor like overleaf. It has almost all the necessary packages(& updated), Journal templates, and auto-completion, etc. You will also find the error messages are more meaningful.